# Jquery flot and week numbers

Tags: jquery, flot

I've plotted some nice graphs with jquery flot. On the x-as the weeknumber is displayed. I would like to display the weeknumbers of the winter season (oct-apr) but that is not possible 'cos flot likes a straight set (0,1,2,3,4 etc) and not (49, 50, 51, 52, 1, 2 etc).
Does anyone know how to fix it?
http://sionvalais.com/snowcondition/andermatt/36